# How to create a password protected project Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make a password protected project in Visual Studio 2010. Is there an option in Visual Studio to protect the project folder from being accessed without a password or something?

I need this to protect my projects from other nosy people, or an external program of some sort.

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I don't give nosy people touch my computer.

Comment: If source code is on common computer then Properties-Security and if source code shared  on multiple conmputers then TFS or old gold SourceSafe

Comment: set a password on your computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no an option like this.

Anyway, protecting a folder with a password is a really bad idea because brute forcing it could be really easy.

I suggest you use [TrueCrypt](https://www.truecrypt.org/) to create a protected storage and use that like container, mounting it when you need and dismounting it when you're not sitting in front of your PC.

Answer (score -1):

You can not do that inside Visual Studio, but what you *can* do like a *possible* solution if I **right** understood your trouble is use of source control.

Push your code in some `source control` (there are a lot of free of them) and even if something goes wrong (for 1000 possible reasons) you always will have a possibility to investigate history of issue and roolback unnecessary changes back.

Commits to `source control` **can** be protected by your password, instead.

Hope this helps.